# Management Cert not in cloud

Tags: azure, x509certificate

I am trying to publish to the Azure platform but having issues with Management Cert.

I have done the following

1. downloaded the publish settings file for my subscription
2. imported into VS
3. ensured all my config files ref the correct cert thumbprint

When I go to publish to staging I get the following:

```
16:09:30 - Error: Certificate: ‘AzureServiceManagementCert’ with Thumbprint: [*****98AB********93242F0F***] for Role: [DEPLOYMENT] has not been uploaded to the cloud service: [SERVICE].
16:09:30 - The deployment cannot be completed because it requires certificates which are not present in the cloud.
```

I go to the Azure management portal and can see the cert under the general settings. 
I go to the dashboard for the cloud service and no cert is present.

How do I get the cert to be linked with the cloud service?

I have looked at importing the cert from my local machine but it is embedded in the publish settings file and from what I gather awkward to extract. 
Is there an easy way to get the cert that was generated as part of the publish settings file to be linked with the cloud service active for the same subscription?

Answer (score 0):

There are management certifications, then there are cloud service specific certificates (application centric). It sounds like you're trying to link a management certificate to the application as a cloud service specific certificate. So I'm guessing your application is trying to access the management API.

The two types of certs (management and application) are stored in separate areas. So that's why you're receiving the error. For security purposes, you can't export a management certificate from the portal. But you should be able to export it from your local machine certificate store once you've imported the publish settings (you can do this via VS or powershell).

Optionally, you can generate your own certificate to be used by both. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg551722.aspx This might be an easier route since you don't have to hunt down the existing certificate in the local cert store.